# Date Format JavaScript in a large array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
[Sun Sep 08 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Sep 15 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Sep 22 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Sep 29 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Oct 06 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Oct 13 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Oct 20 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Oct 27 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Nov 03 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Nov 10 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Nov 17 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Nov 24 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Dec 01 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Dec 08 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Dec 15 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Dec 22 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Dec 29 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Jan 05 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Jan 12 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Jan 19 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Jan 26 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Feb 02 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Feb 09 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Feb 16 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Feb 23 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Mar 01 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Mar 08 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Mar 15 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Mar 22 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Mar 29 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Apr 05 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Apr 12 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Apr 19 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Apr 26 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun May 03 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun May 10 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun May 17 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun May 24 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun May 31 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Jun 07 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Jun 14 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Jun 21 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Jun 28 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Jul 05 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Jul 12 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Jul 19 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Jul 26 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Aug 02 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Aug 09 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Aug 16 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Aug 23 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Sun Aug 30 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)]
```

in this, I need dd/mm/yy format JavaScript

Comment: please, add more description.

Comment: I want a date format entire array [23/Aug/2020, 30/Aug/2020 ......]

Comment: The content of data have an invalid data type. It either should be objects, string or any other data type

Comment: x.map(val=>{ return (val.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + val.getDate() + "-" + val.getFullYear()})

Answer (score 0):

```
x.map(val=>{ return (val.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + val.getDate() + "-" + val.getFullYear()})
```

Comment: Code-only answers are problematic. Please [edit] to describe what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toLocaleDateString("en-US")`:

```js
const formattedDates = dates.map(date => date.toLocateDateString("en-US"))
```

For the provided string of dates, it returns this:

```js
["9/8/2019", "9/15/2019", "9/22/2019", "9/29/2019", "10/6/2019", "10/13/2019", "10/20/2019", "10/27/2019", "11/3/2019", "11/10/2019", "11/17/2019", "11/24/2019", "12/1/2019", "12/8/2019", "12/15/2019", "12/22/2019", "12/29/2019", "1/5/2020", "1/12/2020", "1/19/2020", "1/26/2020", "2/2/2020", "2/9/2020", "2/16/2020", "2/23/2020", "3/1/2020", "3/8/2020", "3/15/2020", "3/22/2020", "3/29/2020", "4/5/2020", "4/12/2020", "4/19/2020", "4/26/2020", "5/3/2020", "5/10/2020", "5/17/2020", "5/24/2020", "5/31/2020", "6/7/2020", "6/14/2020", "6/21/2020", "6/28/2020", "7/5/2020", "7/12/2020", "7/19/2020", "7/26/2020", "8/2/2020", "8/9/2020", "8/16/2020", "8/23/2020", "8/30/2020"]
```